# Block gwt DisclosurePanel on open state

Tags: gwt

How may I block a gwt DisclosurePanel on the open state ?

I mean, how can I prevent this DisclosurePanel to close if the user click the header more than once ?

(My header is a textBox, I want the user to enter a text, and the panel should remain open if the user unfocus the textBox and focus newly by clicking it. The DisclosurePanel content has a "cancel" button that closes the panel)

Thank you very much.

I edit my question after 2 first answers: I would like to avoid to reopen the DisclosurePanel once closed to avoid flashing effect. I actually want to prevent the DisclosurePanel to close. Maybe sinkEvents can help me... if so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [NativePreviewHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.NativePreviewHandler.html) receives all events before they are fired to their handlers. By registering a nativePreviewHandler the first time your disclosurePanel is opened, you can cancel the click event. You can later decide to remove this handler by `preventClose.removeHandler();`

```
HandlerRegistration preventClose = null;
....
panel.addOpenHandler(new OpenHandler<DisclosurePanel>() {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(OpenEvent<DisclosurePanel> event) {
        if (preventClose == null){
            preventClose = Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
                    if (event.getTypeInt()==Event.ONCLICK && event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget() == panel.getHeader().getElement().cast()) 
                        event.cancel();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: One remark - the code above does not compile. We're trying to assign a value to ```preventClose``` variable, which must be ```final``` as it is used within anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is review the javadoc here: https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html

There is a setOpen() method that: Changes the visible state of this DisclosurePanel.

Set it to false from a click event to capture the user action.

Comment: Many thanks to Joel an JamesDrinkard for the quick response. I already know about the setOpen() method, but I am looking for a way to prevent the DisclosurePanel to close and reopen to avoid flashing effect...

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc is right here: https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html
jamesDrinkard pointed the old 1.5 javadoc.

You can use the `addCloseHandler(CloseHandler<DisclosurePanel> handler)` method to add a handler so when the user tries to close it you can reopen it again with `setOpen()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but it worked for me (maybe just one of both will work too):

```
    dPanel.setOpen(true);

    dPanel.addOpenHandler(new OpenHandler<DisclosurePanel>() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(OpenEvent<DisclosurePanel> event) {
            dPanel.setOpen(true);
        }
    });

    dPanel.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<DisclosurePanel>() {
        @Override
        public void onClose(CloseEvent<DisclosurePanel> event) {
            dPanel.setOpen(true);
        }
    });
```